# Django 2.1 deployment on centos 7 with apache, mod_wsgi, python3 venv

Tags: centos7, python, django, mod-wsgi

I've stumbled with this seemingly most relevant deployment option because guides seem to either reference mod_wsgi with python2, or deployment on deb based systems where expected paths are different.
So I'm following these steps:

```
#repos for python3.6, wsgi for python3.6
yum install epel-release centos-release-scl

#base packages
yum install python36 python36-devel httpd httpd-devel rh-python36-mod_wsgi

#python3.6 venv
cd /var/www; 
python36 -m venv django-venv
source django-venv/bin/activate
pip3 install django

#apache config to support wsgi
edit /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf to include
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
```

apache config to serve django content located at /var/www/mysite

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerAdmin foo@mysite.com
 ServerName mysite.com
 ServerAlias www.mysite.com

 WSGIDaemonProcess mysite python-home=/var/www/django-venv/ python-path=/var/www/django-venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages
 WSGIProcessGroup mysite
 WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py

 Alias /static /var/www/mysite/static
 <Directory /var/www/mysite/mysite/static>
  Require all granted
 </Directory>

 <Directory /var/www/mysite/mysite>
  <Files wsgi.py>
  Require all granted
  </Files>
 </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

SEL changes:
`chown apache:apache -R /var/www/mysite
chown apache:apache -R /var/www/django-venv`

httpd starts successfully but I keep getting the following in the error log:

```
Current thread 0x00007f5b5a486880 (most recent call first):
[Fri Nov 23 14:29:02.019635 2018] [core:notice] [pid 4837] AH00052: child pid 5159 exit signal Aborted (6)
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'
```

Could you guys confirm what am I missing in the steps so far for this setup?

Some other info:
`ll /etc/httpd/modules/*wsgi*
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 966K Nov 23 09:13 /etc/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so`

```
systemctl status -l httpd
● httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
Active: active (running) since Fri 2018-11-23 14:26:16 EET; 13min ago
Docs: man:httpd(8)
man:apachectl(8)
Main PID: 4837 (httpd)
Status: "Total requests: 3; Current requests/sec: 0; Current traffic:   0 B/sec"
CGroup: /system.slice/httpd.service
├─4837 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
├─4839 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
├─4840 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
├─4841 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
├─4842 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
├─4843 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
└─4850 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
Nov 23 14:26:16 www1 systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Nov 23 14:26:16 www1 httpd[4837]: AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using fe80::a7a7:b61c:5ffc:b91a. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
Nov 23 14:26:16 www1 systemd[1]: Started The Apache HTTP Server.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got everything to work. Here are the full steps:

```
yum install epel-release centos-release-scl 
yum install python36 python36-devel httpd httpd-devel rh-python36-mod_wsgi`
```

Check if `rh-python36-mod_wsgi` places everything in correct dirs

```
rpm -ql rh-python36-mod_wsgi
```

If found in:

```
/opt/rh/httpd24/root/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/10-rh-python36-wsgi.conf  
/opt/rh/httpd24/root/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_rh-python36-wsgi.so
```

Move them to:

```
/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/10-rh-python36-wsgi.conf  
/etc/httpd/modules/mod_rh-python36-wsgi.so
```

Create python3 venv. if you're moving from somewhere, not creating in, check SEL to make sure apache can use it

```
cd /var/www
python36 -m venv django-venv
source /var/www/django-venv/activate
```

Configure virtual host at /etc/httpd/conf.d/django.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName mysite.com
ServerAlias www.mysite.com


WSGIDaemonProcess mysite python-home=/var/www/django-venv python-path=/var/www/mysite
WSGIProcessGroup mysite
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py

Alias /static /var/www/mysite/static
<Directory /var/www/mysite/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/mysite/mysite>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

If project is moved to `/var/www`, restore correct SEL labels:

```
restorecon -Rv /var/www
```

Make project dir owned by apache:

```
chown -R apache:apache /var/www/mysite
```

If SQLite is used, allow SEL to permit apache access to it (improvement needed):

```
semanage boolean -p http_unified on
```