# Are mod_wsgi, python3-mod_wsgi and libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3 the same thing? Do i need just one for Django on RHEL 7.6?

Tags: django, rhel7, mod-wsgi

I see a couple of tutorials mentioning the Gate Interface specific to python3.6 for Ubuntu -- `libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3` as opposed to just `mod_wsgi` in RHEL's case.

Should i be worrying about looking for specific python package on redhat or will just the module do for `httpd`-hosting Django? Asking because i can't quite find a similar "python36-mod_wsgi" package with `yum`:

```
[me@myserver modules]$ sudo yum list available | grep mod_wsgi
mod_wsgi-debuginfo.x86_64       3.4-18.el7        rhel-x86_64-server-7-debuginfo
[me@myserver modules]$
```

Thanks a ton, new to RHEL.

Answer (score 1):

mod_wsgi is not the same as python3-mod-wsgi as the latter is compiled against python3; whereas the former is against the default python version.  If you install python3-mod-wsgi, then you'll need to have python3 installed as well since python3-mod-wsgi won't like the default python version.

Have a look at [1]

[1] - [Django 2.1 deployment on centos 7 with apache, mod_wsgi, python3 venv](https://serverfault.com/questions/941341/django-2-1-deployment-on-centos-7-with-apache-mod-wsgi-python3-venv)